# Powershell - Trouble passing Validateset parameters into ForEach-Object, getting prompt

Tags: powershell, validateset, foreach-object

So I'm new to PowerShell, and I'm trying to get this function to work.
I have 2 ValidateSet arrays with 3 parameters. These parameters are supposed to change the file path and copy them over from one server to another. For some reason, I keep getting the command prompt for the parameters instead of them passing through. I'm guessing it's an issue with the ForEach-Object, but I'm at a loss. It IS, however, working for the $ArchivePath. I'm new, so please be gentle... TIA

```
param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet("One", "Two", "Three")]
    [string[]]$Channel

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Alias('Phase')]
    [ValidateSet("Devl", "Test", "Prod")]
    [string[]]$Phase

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$FilenameFilter = '.csv'

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$CreateTrigger
    )


function ExitWithCode { param($exitcode) $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode); exit $exitcode }

$exitcode = 0

try {

    # Get a list of files on the host server.
    #
   $files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path "\\ServerName\d\Extract\$Phase\FileTransfer\$Channel\Outbound"        

    # Destination directory.
    #
    $LocalPath = "\\ServerName\d\Extract\$Phase\FileTransfer\$Channel\Outbound"     #for testing


    # Set up folder name for Archive server. Formated as YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS  YYYYMMDD --> Var_Date, 'T' --> Var_Constant & HHMMSS --> Var_Time
    #
    $Var_Date = get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
    $Var_Constant = 'T'
    $Var_Time = get-date -UFormat "%H-%M-%S"
    $Var_Fulldate = $Var_Date + $Var_Constant + $Var_Time

    $ArchivePath = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop\$Channel\$Var_Fulldate"     #For testing
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $ArchivePath


    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ArchivePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { $ArchivePath = $Env:TEMP }

    #Look for files in Outbound directory and remove
    Get-ChildItem -File -Path $LocalPath | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName } #Using copy instead of remove for test
    $FileCount = 0

Write-Output Try2   #for testing
pause               #for testing

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        if ((-not $file.IsDirectory) -and ($File.FullName -match $FilenameFilter)) {

            $localfilename = $LocalPath + $file.Name

            if (Test-Path $localfilename) { Copy-Item $localfilename }

            try {

                Copy-Item -Path $(Join-Path -Path $LocalPath -ChildPath $file.Name) -Destination $ArchivePath
    #Remove files from outbound since they've been archived
    #
                #Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName

            "Retrieved file $file"

                $FileCount++
            }
            catch {
                Write-Output Try13  #for testing
                $exitcode = 13
                "failed to retrieve $file"
            }
            finally {
                $error.Clear()
            }
        }
    }

}
catch {
Write-Output Try3
    $exitcode = 14
}
finally {
Write-Output Try4
    $error.Clear()
}

if ($CreateTrigger -and ($exitcode -eq 0) -and ($FileCount -gt 0)) {
    New-Item -Path "$LocalPath\Trigger_File.trg" -ItemType File | Out-Null
}

#ExitWithCode $exitcode     # take out for testing
```

The output:

```
PS C:\Users\me> \\Server\blah\USERS\me\My Documents\Folder\Get-FileName_t4.ps1
cmdlet Get-FileName_t4.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Channel[0]: Three
Channel[1]: 
Phase[0]: Devl
Phase[1]: 


    Directory: C:\Users\me\Desktop\Three


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                
d-----       11/22/2019  12:17 PM                2019-11-22T12-17-23                                                                                 
Try2
Press Enter to continue...: 
Retrieved file File1_20191122080912.csv
Retrieved file File2_20191122080922.csv
Retrieved file File3_20191122080925.csv
Retrieved file File4_20191122080932.csv
Retrieved file File5_20191122080933.csv
Retrieved file File6_20191122080933.csv
Try4
```

Comment: your code says `(Mandatory = $true)` for both the `$Phase` & `$Channel` parameters ... and you don't provide them in your call to the script. i am kinda curious where the `Phs` in `$PhsPhase` is coming from in your output text, tho. [*grin*]

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give me an example?

Comment: it looks like `Bender the Greatest` has given you the example you need ... simply provide the _required by your code_ parameter values on the line that calls the  script. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting prompted because you're not passing in those parameters but `Mandatory=$true` is set on the arguments you are getting prompted for. Since your session is interactive, it asks you to input the correct values. If you don't want to get prompted, provide the mandatory arguments:

```
"\\Server\blah\USERS\me\My Documents\Folder\Get-FileName_t4.ps1" -Channel Three -Phase Dev1
```

---

A couple of other things I noticed:

- You don't need to provide `Mandatory=$false`, as `Mandatory` is `$false` by default
- Setting an alias of `Phase` for the `-Phase` argument is also redundant